# regex for comma separated dates in php

Tags: regex

I have a problem to set regular expression for multiple dates with comma separator.
I have dates like as :

```
2017-03-25, 2017-03-27, 2017-03-28
```

please help me guys.....

i am trying to set php validation for selecting multi dates (jquery calender).

my regex is :

```
$value = "2017-03-25, 2017-03-27, 2017-03-28";
preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])([0-9])*$/",$value)
```

Comment: What is the Problem with your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are matching only a single date with 0+ digits after it with your regex.

You may use the following fix:

```
^([0-9]{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))(?:,\s*(?1))*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IZu6ks/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `([0-9]{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))` - Group 1 matching and capturing a date-like substring
- `(?:,\s*(?1))*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `,`  - comma
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces (remove `*` to only match one, or use `?` to match 1 or 0 whitespaces)
  - `(?1)` - recurse Group 1 subpattern
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: @Wiktor   That "(?1) - recurse Group 1 subpattern" is one hell of an amazing thing ... but does that work only in php ? I mean with the exact syntax... just went to your link and change the langauge to python, go, javascript and it didn't work ... curious to know :)

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman: It is not working in Python, however, it works with Boost (e.g. Notepad++), too. You may use `\g<1>` instead of `(?1)` in Ruby (i.e. Onigmo library). In Python, PyPi regex module supports `(?1)` subroutine calls, too.